# IE reverts back to before changes

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I am having a problem with a page on my site, basically you choose a a few options and then submit the changes to the database and the page refreshes and displays the updated changes, but then if I click on the URL tab at the top of IE8 and press ENTER on the keyboard the page reverts back to before the changes where made???? its really confusing me, but then if I refresh the page again with the refresh button then the changes I made come back again.

Any help with why this is happening would be great?

I am using PHP and Javascript on my webpage.

Regards
Alistair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the URL have variables within it?  If not IE is using **[caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache)**.

When you visit a site in any modern browser it will store it's own local copy of that page.  When you then go to the URL tab at the top and press enter again the browser realises it has it's own local copy, and chooses to show you this instead.

This improves the responsiveness of every page you visit on the internet, however when you refresh the page it checks the HTTP header from the server and if it has changed (it has) it will show the new version of the page.

You need to prevent caching, to do that in PHP just add the following:

```
// Disable caching of the current document:
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');// Date in the past
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

or you could even use [META tags](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm).

Please note that regardless of what you do, these are simply requests that the browser can ignore at will.  You have no control of the client's browser, although most will comply.

Comment: I have variables within my webpage...php variables and javascript variables but not within the actual URL. So if it is caching, is there a way round this?? because users who visit my site I would rather them not have that problem!? thanks a lot m.edmondson.

Comment: Ok, just to check I'm answering the correct problem can you post of the URL that is in the address bar when the problem occurs?

Comment: Do you think it is a caching problem then? hopefully there is a way round it!

Comment: It is definitely a caching problem - you might have noticed the images changing, I'm taking a look for you ;-)

Comment: just so you know...its not finished the page its just the core of it working haha I know its not very pretty. Thanks for you time! I hope you can find the solution!. And yeah! its the images reverting back to the previous selection that is the problem, it doesnt happen in chrome or firefox though!.

Comment: I can confirm it is definitely a cache problem, using Fiddler when I request the page (the second time) there is no activity over the wire, hence IE is just showing you what it had saved first time around.  I've done a quick search and [this article may have what you want](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm).

Comment: The link was perfect! your a diamond! thanks a lot for your time!.

Comment: No problem at all! You might be interested in [my blog](http://matthewedmondson.info) as a way to contact me again.